# "widetext" not recognized in TeXstudio

Tags: environments, texstudio, revtex

I use "revtex4-1" document class in TeXstudio. But I find that the environment "widetext" is labeled "command not recognized" even after I check the box before the term "revtex4-1.cwl" in the "Completion" for configuration.

The question is: how can I make TeXstudio recognize "widetext"?

Answer (score 1):

from [FAQ: Why does TeXstudio mark a command as unrecognized](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-texstudio-mark-a-command-as-unrecognized):

> TXS checks all LaTeX commands in the document for validity. This helps you recognizing errors (typos and not loaded packages) already while typing. If a command is marked as unrecognized, TXS did not find a definition for it. See [How does TXS know about valid commands?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands) for more details.

For information how to solve the issue, follow the links above.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of widetext.sty:

```
\usepackage{widetext}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
```

Save the following content as widetext.sty and place it in the same directory as the .tex file

```
%%---------------------------------------------------

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{widetext}

%% Mimics the widetext environment of revtex4 for any other class package
%% Eg: article.cls
%%
%% Compiled by: Anjishnu Sarkar
%%
%% Advantages:
%% *) Supports float (eg: figure) in two column format (Advantage over
%%      multicol package)
%% *) One and twocolumn exist on the same page
%% *) Flow of text shown via rule
%% *) Equal height of text when in two column format
%%
%% Acknowledgment(s):
%% 1. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, two packages (flushend, cuted) of
%% the sttools bundle are used. The sttools bundle is available from CTAN.
%% Lisence of these packages rests with their corresponding author.
%% Any bug/problem with flushend and cuted should be forwarded to their
%% corresponding package authors.
%% 2. The idea of the rule came from the following latex community website
%% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2770
%%
%% This package just defines the widetext environment and the rules.
%%
%% Usage:
%% \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{article}
%% \usepackage{widetext}
%%
%% \begin{document}
%%
%% Some text in twocolumn
%%
%% \begin{widetext}
%% Text in onecolumn format.
%% \end{widetext}
%%
%% Some more text in twocolumn
%%
%% \end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Package required for equal height while in 2 columns format
\IfFileExists{flushend.sty}
    {\RequirePackage{flushend}}
    {\typeout{}
    \typeout{Package widetext error: Install the flushend package which is
    a part of sttools bundle. Available from CTAN.}
    \typeout{}
    \stop
    }

%% Package required for onecolumn and twocolumn to exist on the same page.
%% and also required for widetext environment.
\IfFileExists{cuted.sty}
    {\RequirePackage{cuted}}
    {\typeout{}
    \typeout{Package widetext error: Install the cuted package which is
    a part of sttools bundle. Available from CTAN.}
    \typeout{}
    \stop
    }


\newlength\@parindent
\setlength\@parindent{\parindent}

\if@twocolumn
    \newenvironment{widetext}
        {%
            \begin{strip}
            \rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-0.4pt)}{0.4pt}%
            \rule{0.4pt}{6pt}
            \par %\vspace{6pt}
            \parindent \@parindent
        }%
        {%
            \par
            \hfill\rule[-6pt]{0.4pt}{6.4pt}%
            \rule{\dimexpr(0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep-1pt)}{0.4pt}
            \end{strip}
        }
\else
    \newenvironment{widetext}{}{}
\fi
```